# Report: IgnoringInactive: a bug?

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, hold

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

Just to report.

`IgnoringInactive`should work with `Cases`. In agreement with the things written at the Documentation Center this:

```
 Cases[{Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b]}, IgnoringInactive[Cos[x_]]]
```

works correctly  yielding

```
(*   {Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b]}   *)
```

exactly as expected.

However, this

```
Cases[{Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b], Tan[c]}, IgnoringInactive[Cos[x_]]]
```

works (as I think) incorrectly returning

```
(*  {Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b], Tan[c]}  *)
```

while I would expect again `{Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b]}`.

Comment: I agree: that doesn't seem right.  It seems `IgnoringInactive[Inactive[Cos][x_]]` does work however, not that that makes this OK.

Comment: On a related note, `MatchQ[1, IgnoringInactive[0]]` and `MatchQ["a", IgnoringInactive["b"]]` both return `True` instead of `False` (reported to WRI).

Answer (score 1):

Since `IgnoringInactive` is presently bugged we may wish to have a workaround for this operation.
Here is my first attempt at implementing this.  Please test it and give me feedback.

```
patternHead = 
  Pattern | Blank | Repeated | HoldPattern | Verbatim | Inactive | _Alternatives;

ignInac[pat_] := 
 Replace[pat, (h : Except[patternHead])[x___] :> (h | Inactive[h])[x], {0, -1}]
```

Test for an example from the documentation:

```
diff[ignInac[int[f_, x_]], x_] := f

diff[int[Sin[x], x], x]
diff[Inactive[int][Sin[x], x], x]
```

> ```
> Sin[x]
>
> Sin[x]
> ```

And demonstrating correct function with the examples from the question and comments:

```
Cases[{Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b], Tan[c]}, ignInac @ Cos[x_]]
```

> ```
> {Cos[a], Inactive[Cos][b]}
> ```

```
MatchQ[1, ignInac[0]]
MatchQ["a", ignInac["b"]]
```

> ```
> False
> False
> ```

Notes:

- The function `ignInac` directly transforms patterns so definitions do not look as clean as with the built-in, however for the cases I've tried it appears equivalent.
- I did not attempt to handle the case of `HoldPattern` outside of `IgnoringInactive` (or `ignInac`) but I do not see an example of that in the documentation.